# Location of the startpoint of a drawed line and the endpoint

Tags: ios, iphone

I like to develop a project in Xcode with photo pieces. For this project i need the locations of the startpoint and the endpoint of a line drawed by the finger. Then i like to link the two startpoints and the two endpoints of the lines together.

Like this Picture! 
[image]

At first like to connect location 1 to location 2 with a line automatically on each side
And Then i like to copy the content in this square.

How can i perform it?

I would be very thankful for help

Comment: Where are you stuck? Also, you say the "content in this square," but you don't have a square - you have a quadrilateral. Are you planning on converting that to a square that encases the 4 points, or do you want to mask it to the drawn quadrilateral? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sry   i like to copy the content of this quadrilateral elsewhere and safe it.